# What is the thread marker in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I am having difficulties to follow what is written in MSDN article:

- [Walkthrough: Debugging a Multithreaded Application (Visual Studio 2010)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157784%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The section "To discover the thread marker" tells:

> 1. Right-click in the **Threads** window, then click **Show Threads in
>      Source**.
> 2. Look at the gutter on the left side of the window. On this
>      line, you will see an icon that resembles two cloth threads. One
>      thread is red and the other is blue. The thread marker indicates
>      that a thread is stopped at this location. Possibly, thread is
>      stopped at this location  .
>
> ..... This icon is a thread marker:   [image: ThreadMarker]"

I cannot find this thread marker as well as understand what is accomplished ny "click **Show Threads** in Source" (I do not see any differences thereafter)

What is the thread marker and what is accomplished by clicking **Show Threads** in Source"?

Here is my VS2010 screenshot after following the steps:

[image: VS2010 Debugging - Threads]

Comment: You need to switch off of the thread that's stopped first - double click on (I'm guessing here) the line with `ServerClass.StatMethod`, which will change context to that thread - now if you scroll to `Server.InstanceMethod`, you'll probably see that marker.

Comment: The threads in your program are not executing the same code.

Comment: I didn't understand your comments and what should I do in order to follow this walkthrough, i.e. to see "thread marker", what is "Threads in Source" doing. Can you answer what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

without doing anything else that works fine for me.
[image]